# Set-theoretic equality in double dual graph

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, graph-theory, plane-curves

Someone in the math fandom on tumblr was explaining the concept of a dual graph, and he [was asked](http://hpgross.tumblr.com/post/132059913462/matan-matika-dual-graphs-a-cool-thing-that-you) a tough question:

> Is the dual of the dual [equal to] the original graph always, or just isomorphic?

Now, in the usual definition of "dual graph" that I am familiar with is rather informal, as is the one the original user was using to explain the concept. But it seems to me that if we are thinking of a plane graph as an abstract graph together with an embedding, it would be *really* hard to make a definition of the dual such that $G$ was literally, set-theoretically equal to $G^{**}$.

I'd be surprised if this question has any independent interest, but I was wondering if anyone knows a construction, or what sort of tools we might be able to use to construct an impossibility argument.

Comment: Your link is broken; it seems to be linking to a file stored locally on your computer, not a website.

Comment: Weird; thank you. Should be fixed.

Comment: Yup, works fine for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are interested in is called a band decomposition -- here the vertices and faces of the graph are both sets of discs on the surface of a sphere, and the operation of taking the dual *really is* just changing which set of discs you call vertices, and so is in fact a set-theoretic involution (for connected graphs).

Comment: This is a very elegant solution; thank you!